Spaces with free $\pi_1$ but not homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of spheres?
Background
The Rips complex of a metric space $X$ at scale parameter $r \in [0, \infty)$, denoted $\mathcal R(X)_r$, is the simplicial complex with simplices all finite subsets of $X$ with diameter at most $r$.
If $X\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ (with the Euclidean metric), then $\mathcal R(X)_r$ is sometimes called a planar Rips complex.
It was shown by Chambers et al. that if $\mathcal R(X)_r$ is a planar Rips complex then $\pi_1 (\mathcal R(X)_r)$ is free.
It is conjectured that every (path component of a) planar Rips complex has the homotopy type of a wedge sum of spheres. This has been shown to be true for, e.g., $X=S^1$ (source).
Question
What are some examples of topological spaces $Y$ such that $\pi_1(Y)$ is free, but $Y$ is not homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of spheres?
The motivation for this question is that if such a space could be realized (up to homotopy equivalence) as a Euclidean Rips complex, it would be a counterexample to the conjecture.

What about the wedge sum of circles wedge sum a simply connected space that does not have the homotopy type of any sphere (e.g., a complex Grassmannian)?

@TedShifrin That works! I didn't know about that example.

Using a product of spheres as the last factor would less fancy :)

It's not hard to calculate that if $X$ is a wedge of spheres then there aren't any nontrivial cup products in cohomology. So it suffices to take, for example, $Y$ to be any manifold with free $\pi_1$ whose cohomology has nontrivial cup products; a simple example is $S^2 \times S^2$.

Sorry, my alg. top. is a bit weak - isn't $\pi_1(S^2\times S^2)$ trivial?

@Tom: sure, and the trivial group is free (on zero generators). If you want $\pi_1$ to be nontrivial then take a wedge with a bunch of circles.

True! Thank you
